# Can I roll back changes made to my title by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderators, rollbacks

A moderator of some Stack Exchange site has changed my question title. What should I do in case I think the old title has a better connection to the question content?

Comment: I assume this is the question in question? http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/3841/revisions

Comment: Yes. I think the suffix addition "and protocols" have no connection to my question, since I asked about distinguish between packets in the same protocol. Additionally, why to omit the "have a nice week"?

Comment: @Reflection We remove such niceties for reasons described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts I've done the same for this post.

Comment: "have a nice week" is considered noise and it is desirable to omit it

Comment: Consider changing to a title that is the middle position, "detecting" seems far more relevant that "distinction between" but you say the rest is not connected. Use the good parts of both titles to make a 3rd title

Comment: So, just change?

Comment: Or ask the editor by @ing them to find out why they edited. But changing to the a third title you're not rolling back, you're using the best of both

Answer (score 7):

You *can*.

However, *should* you? Try not to, in most cases the mod is making an edit which improves the question.

However, if you think that the mod's edit is *not* improving the question — that means the mod probably didn't understand your question properly. In that case, work on improving our question to make it more clear, as evidently at least one person didn't get what you were trying to say<sup>1</sup>.

You can also ping the mod using the normal @reply in the comments and ask for why he made the change (or to let him know that you reverted it, giving your reasons)

I myself (as a mod) make edits at times when I'm not sure what the OP is saying. Usually I leave a comment telling the OP to check if the changes I made represent his question better, but I may not do so always. As of today (4/11/13), moderators (or any other user) do not yet have a direct line to the user's mind and thus may not interpret your question correctly. That is ok.

If you revert it and the mod (or someone else) changes it back, *then* don't start an edit war, instead discuss it with the mod. I've seen multiple cases when a mod edits to fit the rules better (usually involving the removal of taglines/salutations or the fixing of tags). It's best if these are not reverted.

But if someone edits your post and embeds a misinterpretation about what the post is about in the edit, feel free to revert it, and **try to fix the post so that the misinterpretation would not have happened in the first place**.

<sup>1. Or read it too fast and misinterpreted it. That can happen, too.</sup>

Comment: I'd give them 6–8 decades to implement the feature.

Answer (score 5):

You technically *can* roll back the changes to your title made by a moderator. However, it is likely that you should not. The mod was trying to improve your post and that is desirable.

In this exact scenario, the "jargon" for a packet is a frame.

> A data packet on an Ethernet link is called an Ethernet frame.
>   -[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame)

Determining the type of these frames will depend on their protocols.

> The header features destination and source MAC addresses which have 6 octets each, the EtherType protocol identifier field and optional IEEE 802.1Q tag.

So basically the mod was just trying to make your title more descriptive of the problem (probably for increased searchability).

Titles are important, but here the difference between the two is interesting. One is good for a general audience, and one for a specific audience.

More than likely the moderator is aware of the difference and chose the more appropriate of the two.

Answer (score 1):

If you disagree with an edit then the first and best thing to do is ask the editor. Any editor can be @ replied to. It's likely they've misunderstood your question so it’s likely that larger changes are necessary to the body of the question.

Changing a moderators work is not taboo (on technical matters, don't put the "have a nice week" back), but should certainly not be taken lightly. Try to understand why the edit was made and then take action from there. On the other hand engaging in a rollback war (where the post is repeatedly reverted by both parties) is very much is taboo and must be avoided

Comment: Changing the moderators work or changing the users without moderator privileges should not be differentiated. Some Stackoverflow user with a little reputation can be tehcnically much more better than moderator but for example having less time or less interest for Stackoverflow than moderator

Comment: @MikroDel Indeed, on technical aspects a moderator is just a user; you shouldn't roll back any edit without consideration. On non technical aspects however their edits have more weight

Answer (score -2):

Change it back via edit and thats all

**Updated:**

Was posted before TS shows the question which title was edited.

I have answered the part

> What should I do in case I think the old title has a better connection to the question content?

Comment: You might want to hold back on that though. Collaborative editing is an important feature of the site. Rollbacks are fine if the edits aren't particularly good, or if they are harmful. But don't go rolling back edits just because someone edited.

Comment: Is it acceptable? That is, to reject a change of someone with higher authority.

Comment: @Bart the TS say "..I think the old title have a better connection to the question content.."   its not "..just because someone edited."

Comment: In this case, the OP should probably *not* undo the edit. Getting into an edit war is not a good idea, really. Coming here and learning *why* an edit was made was a good, responsible move.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Moderators are of course not all knowing on technical matters, and this was a technical edit (of the title anyway)

Comment: @MartijnPieters as I posted my answer - it was generally one. TS doesnt show the question at that moment.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Yes, I see that; the moderator probably felt the title was better this way. You can always *ask* an editor, by addressing them in the comments (`@name` pinging works for editors of a post).

Comment: @MikroDel: I don't think it is very *good* answer to the general question either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why not? The question was "What should I do in case I think the old title has a better connection to the question content?" Why is the answer not good?

Comment: Because just rolling back the edit can lead to a edit war. Trying to learn *why* someone edited the way they did would be more constructive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters we are talking about different things. Sure someone who edited the title can be right. Sure he or she can be wrong also. And the question was about the second part.

Comment: @MikroDel: I do not agree that just undoing the edit is the better option here, no. That is what you are saying in your answer, to edit the title back to the original.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - one more time - as I have posted my answer the TS qeustion was "What should I do in case I think the old title has a better connection to the question content?" The question means that TS has analysed the edit, not agreed with it and want the original version back.

Comment: @MikroDel - TS? That's a new one for me. What does it stand for?

Comment: @MikroDel: Yes, I understood that. Your answer was to just edit back the original title. *I don't agree with that answer*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thread (topic) starter

Comment: @MartinSmith: I was wondering that as well. I am mentally substituting 'OP' for that for now.